# mix more than 2 colors together with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I´m trying to add in JS colors together. I´m sitting on front of this problem for days now. The problem is the colors are in hex code.

Now i´d like to add all the colors together to print and print it out in a div, or something.

Could you show me demo plz how to do it ?

Here is a picture of what i mean:

[image]

The hex code is an `<input>` type.

Comment: what do you mean "mix" them? noisy effect like in the background? or you want to combine two colors into one?

Comment: You must be more precise. What is yout problem and what have you tried ? What was the most probent. If your problem is hex comprehension, it has nothing to do with js.

Comment: Are those colors just hard coded (so you just need to have an array of them and then print them out) or do you need to get them from each element?

Comment: Well, `parseInt(hexaValue, 16)` converts hexadecimal to decimal and `decimalValue.toString(16)` converts decimal to hexadecimal, you can combine these two to get what you want

Comment: @LorDex to add them together e.g if i add red blue and green together white will be the "result"

Comment: @TCHdvlp I am trying to get a new "third" color, which is a between the selected colors. I´d just like to add all thsoe colors together to get one color which is the result of all the 13 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "mix", but assuming you to want to combine them, you could do so by using a plugin such as [xcolor](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/).

e.g. `$.xcolor.additive(color, color)` calculates the additive color mix of two colors.

So, you could do something like:

```
var $inputs = $("input"); // You'll want to make this more specific
var color = "";

$inputs.each(function(){
  var curColor = this.value;
  if(color === ""){
    color = curColor;
  }

  color = $.xcolor.additive(color, curColor);
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/jhD54/)**

Comment: yeah thats what i am looking for. 
But is it possible to add all 13 colors together ? 

And with "input" I mean the value of the color is a html <input type text> type. 

And can i print the "combine of the colors" to a div ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add them all together. I've updated my answer with a fiddle, although your combined color seems to come out as white

Comment: If you try removing some of the input elements, you can see that you come out with different shades of purple and red.

Comment: ye, thank you very much. That u´ve created in fiddle i already got it. But the problem is I don´t understand to print the new color out. Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: `console.log(color)` will output an object with a bunch of methods such as `getColor()`, `getHex()` etc. for you to experiment with. You can also do `$(mySelector).css("color", color)`, or just `console.log(color.getColor())`

Comment: MUCH better for me was `$.xcolor.average(color1, color2)`  or actually if I needed 25% white,75% red: `$.xcolor.gradientlevel('#fff', '#f00', 25, 100); `