# Mixing more than two colors with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, colors, frontend

I would like to create a function which is capable of mixing colors, but I got stucked.

I know there is color-mix() function in CSS which is capable to mix two colors, but the problem is that I would like to mix more than two colors. Is there any solution in CSS or JavaScript to handle this? I would appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mix more than 2 colors together with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774519/mix-more-than-2-colors-together-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the colors to the rgb values and get the sum of red, green and blue and divide them through the number of colors that you are mixing.